# Design: What is the best approach to updating part of a database record?

Tags: forms, software-design

This question concerns the best design approach rather than a particular technical technique. I have a database table that contains system user's details i.e: username, password, firstname, lastname (these attributes can only be changed by an administrator). The rest of the user record contains address, phone number, mobile number, etc (these attributes can only be changed by the user).

I therefore need 2 forms, an 'admin' form and a 'user' form, with a different set of editable fields on each, and appropriate role-based security to control usage.

Here are two approaches I could take:

Approach 1. Each form has it's own backing bean representing just the editable fields on the form. On 'Save', the backing bean calls a specific DAO method (e.g. UpdateUser_Admin or UpdateUser_User) to perform a partial update of the user record. This approach therefore involves 2 forms, a backing bean for each form, and 2 methods in the DAO class.

Approach 2. There are 2 forms as before, but each form re-creates the entire User object through the use of input fields for the editable fields and hidden fields for the non-editable fields. Both forms would use the same backing bean representing ALL of the User attributes. There would only need to be one method in the DAO - to update ALL fields in the User record.

The second approach seems to make sense to me, but I'm new to development and I'd be grateful if readers could advise if I'm missing something. I've already considered splitting the User table into 2 separate tables but that is not practical in this case. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: The first approach is safer. With the second approach, someone who would want to hack the system could easily change the hidden, non-editable fields with the debugging tools built in to the browser and change details that they are not supposed to change, if you don't have additional checks in place.

Comment: @Jesper you must perform double validation (server / client) in all cases avoiding this modifications in the view.

Comment: As for me, the easiest approach is to split the table into two tables: `User` and `UserDetails` which have parent-child relationship. Then you don't have to bother about which part of data to be edited by whom. Then you have one form to edit the user data and the other for editing the user detail data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As a rule: don't create DAO methods updating only a single field / attribute.
- Don't split `User` entity into 2 tables.
- DAO are created to manage entities, thus **use one DAO for each class and code only a single update method for each DAO.**
- If you are not sure of having the complete entity follow this steps **in the service layer**

  - get data from form (at least id and field you want to update)
  - retrieve `Object` representing entity from database (with `DAO::readById(id)` for example)
  - update the field you need in the java `Object`
  - call `DAO::update`

    **NOTE:** I ommited populating `DTO` to `DBO` objects

Comment: Thank you. I'm at the stage where I know the technical techniques but I can't find a discussion of design considerations in the (many) books I have on JSF. If you know of a good one I'd be delighted to know.

Comment: glad to help, anyway, this is a broad questions, many answers can be correct depending of the needs, **I just made a fast analysis** with small info you provided, but I think you can use as guide *in this case* and carefully looking deeper if you need to enlarge the class. Of course, be carefully double validating data in view to avoid security issues.